# What were the intended targets of SCP-631?

Tags: scp-foundation

[SCP-631](http://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-631) is a parasitic organism, apparently created as a weapon to hunt down someone's enemies. We know that those enemies were intended to be isolated targets sleeping outside at night, but the work hints that they were far more specific, but also that the aforementioned mechanism had a very low false positive rate.

What class of people was SCP-631 created to kill?

Comment: Not sure if you're going to get an answer - a lot SCP stuff is pretty much contained in the one article, although there are sometimes references to other SCP items - if it isn't already mentioned in SCP-631, it probably isn't mentioned anywhere

Comment: @horuskol - it's more that someone else may be able to put the pieces together as I could not. It definitely sounded like they had something in mind.

Comment: A legitimate answer cannot be provided for this question, the page you linked to provides the totality of available information on the subject.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [Discussion](http://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/forum/t-745271/scp-631) section of the site it is mentioned that the last note of the page is a reference to homeless people and the election of Rudolph "Rudy" Giuliani:

> The following is also handwritten, but appears to be a formal letter:

```
Your offer is accepted. The payment will be transferred upon completion of the project.

Those miserable reprobates are going to destroy any chance of my reelection if the 

situation is not handled swiftly. I don't care what you have to do to take care of it, do it.

████ ████████
```

> Fingerprints on the letter are consistent with Dr. Forsythe and ███████ "████" ████████.

Comment: And people said it couldn't be answered. ;)